# Jupyter not recognising numpy (using homebrew pyenv)

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

I followed [these](https://towardsdatascience.com/managing-virtual-environment-with-pyenv-ae6f3fb835f8) instructions to get a python virtual environment (managed by pyenv) working in a Jupyter Notebook.

In summary, I did

```
brew install pyenv
pyenv install 3.8.5
pyenv virtualenv 3.8.5 myproject
pyenv shell myproject 
pip install jupyter notebook matplotlib pandas numpy scipy
```

Then I started up jupyter notebook from terminal (I tried both `jupyter notebook` and `jupyter lab`). When I typed `import numpy as np`, I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-0aa0b027fcb6> in <module>
----> 1 import numpy as np

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

But in the very next cell, if I evaluate `!pip install numpy`, I get

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /Users/<my_username>/.pyenv/versions/3.8.5/envs/myproject/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.19.1)
```

And also, `!which python` and `!which pip` return

```
/Users/<my_username>/.pyenv/shims/pip
/Users/<my_username>/.pyenv/shims/python
```

How is it even possible that in the very same jupyter notebook, it can't find numpy but pip says numpy is already installed? I can never seem to get my Python environments to just behave!

Comment: Could you add the result of `which jupyter`?

Comment: From within the same notebook, `/Users/<my_username>/.pyenv/shims/jupyter`

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. I think it's all due to your "varying pip list". You probably have installed bunch of libraries via `pip install` before you created the shims path (prior your `pyenv` installation). You may also have installed some others after the shims creation. So your jupyter-notebook and jupyter-lab may not have access to the priorly installed libraries.

Since you have installed `pyenv` via `homebrew`, without touching anything else just re-installing the `jupyterlab` via `homebrew` might take care of it.

I used this:

```
brew install jupyterlab
```

And it solved my problem.

source: https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/jupyterlab